# Interrupt handler does not work on a real computer

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, bootloader

I'm writing a bootloader-like program that changes default interrupt handler for the keyboard interrupt (int 0x9). It works on bochs and qemu, but not on a real computer, where it prints 'A' only once and then it does not react to pressing any key. (It should print the char at least twice, one time for pressing and one for releasing). How can I make the program work correctly? I'm using gcc. Kernel code:

```
asm(".code16gcc\n");

typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) FullAddr{
    ushort offset;
    ushort seg;
} FullAddr;

#define MAIN_CODE_START 0x9200

asm (
    "xorw %ax, %ax\n\t"
    "movw %ax, %ds\n\t"
    /*Linker places the start of the .data section at this address */
    "movw (0x9202), %ax\n\t"
    "movw %ax, %ds\n\t"
    "movw %ax, %ss\n\t"
    "movw $0xFFFB, %sp\n\t" 
    "jmp main"
);

void print_char(char c){
    asm volatile("int  $0x10" : : "a"(0x0E00 | c), "b"(7));
}

void get_int_addr(ushort interrupt, FullAddr *addr)
{
    asm volatile(
        "pushw %%ds\n\t"
        "movw %w3, %%ds\n\t"
        "movw (%w2), %w0\n\t"
        "movw 2(%w2), %w1\n\t"
        "popw %%ds"
        : "=c"(addr->offset), "=a"(addr->seg):"b"(interrupt*4),"a"(0)
    );
}

void set_int_addr(ushort interrupt, uint func){
    asm volatile(
        "cli\n\t"
        "pushw %%ds\n\t"
        "movw %w2, %%ds\n\t"
        "movw %w0, (%w1)\n\t"
        "movw %%cs, 2(%w1)\n\t"
        "popw %%ds\n\t"
        "sti"
        : : "c"(func-MAIN_CODE_START), "b"(interrupt*4), "a"(0):
    );
}

void wait(uint usec)
{
    asm volatile("int $0x15": : "a"(0x8600), "c"(usec>>16), "d"(usec&0xFFFF));
}

FullAddr addr;

void handler_func(){
    print_char('A');
}

void handler();
asm(
    "handler:\n\t"
    "pushal\n\t"
    "call handler_func\n\t"
    "popal\n\t"
    "ljmp *addr\n\t"
    "iret\n\t"
);

void main(){
    get_int_addr(9, &addr);
    set_int_addr(9, (uint)handler);
    while(1){
        wait(1000);
    }
}
```

The full project can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y53iwc34avhzoob/ar.zip?dl=0), it includes floppy image. To build it, launch files build.sh and build_main.sh.

Update:
I've tried @RossRidge code — the `lcall` instruction jumps to 0xfe9e6 instead of 0xfe897 and there is an infinite loop. `handler` code:

```
asm(
    "handler:\n\t"
    "pushw %ds\n\t"
    "pushal\n\t"
    "xorw %ax, %ax\n\t"
    "movw %ax, %ds\n\t"
    "movw (0x9202), %ax\n\t"
    "movw %ax, %ds\n\t"
    "call handler_func\n\t"
    "popal\n\t"
    "pushf\n\t"
    "lcall *addr\n\t"
    "popw %ds\n\t"
    "iret\n\t"
);
```

Update2: I've figured out that I have to use `lcallw` instead, but the infinite loop remains. After `iret` execution goes to 0xfe9e6 and then back to `iret`.

Comment: You should move the asm statement in`handler` outside of the function so you don't have to worry about what instructions the compiler generates in front of it. It's not safe to make BIOS calls in interrupt routines. You should use a direct screen write if you want to show something on screen during an interrupt. USB keyboards don't generate IRQ 1, and so keypresses may not end up invoking INT 9.

Comment: You should move the "toplevel assembly" (both the start part and the handler function) outside of C files, it is really confusing (looks like Ross misread it) - I didn't know you could even do that reliably.

Comment: @RossRidge I don't understand what you said about the `handler`. It is not a C function, it is written in assembly. And I've checked the generated code in the bochs debugger. I've also tried not to make BIOS calls in the interrupt routine, setting a variable there and then checking it in the main loop, but with the same effect.  And the routine is definitely called, because a char is printed.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Having the declaration of `handler` right next to the asm statement make it look like they were a function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely the `ljmp *addr` statement. The memory location `addr` is relative to DS, but in an interrupt handler this can be anything. Since its almost certain that the handler will be called in the context of the BIOS code that handles `int $0x15, %ah = 0x85`, DS will be set to whatever the BIOS sets it to, not what your code sets it to.

The simple solution would be to make memory location relative to CS with `ljmp *%cs:addr`, but your code uses different values for CS and DS so that won't work.  You should really fix that so they're the same, but failing that you'll have to use something like `ljmp *cs:addr-0x9200`.

Comment: I've tried setting %ds inside of the interrupt routine instead and it worked.

Comment: @Imieee If you set %ds in the interrupt routine, is it being destroyed upon exit from the handler?

Comment: @Imieee You'd have to do more than or else you'd be trashing DS. If you want to go that route you'll need to use something like `push %ds; ...; pushf; lcall *addr; pop %ds`.

Comment: The funny thing about the `ljmp` is that I wrote a comment about it an hour ago and removed it!

Comment: @Imieee : Personally I'd put all data that may be required by the interrupt handlers into the same segment as the interrupt handler code. That was there is little overhead and you should be able use the segment %cs directly.